# Laravel 4 pretty ulrs not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using xampp 1.8.3.

My .htacces (in public folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

All the "AllowOverride" of the httpd.conf are set to "All".

Uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I don't use virtualhosts (should I?).

`/public/index.php/something` works but `/public/something` does not.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are the path's set right?

check the following

1. open your /app/config/app.php and check if the value of url is set to the right path, eg.

   `'url' => 'http://localhost/laravel',`
2. then open the /public/.htaccess and add a the RewriteBase rule under the RewriteEngine On line, eg.

   `RewriteBase /laravel/public/`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I did the same thing. This is my url 'http://localhost/Laravel/public/', with the above setup if I am trying  'http://localhost/Laravel/' then I am getting the directory. I am stuck with it.

Comment: are both values right? is the .htaccess file in the location/Laravel directory and is ist named .htaccess and not something else?

Answer (score 0):

In the application config change the following

'index' => 'index.php'

t0

'index' => ''

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Virtual host is just a decoration that you can get while development. Its mostly like providing an alias to something like

```
http://localhost/myappname/public/
```

to get a better name like app.dev or something.

To remove index.php, I think you should just change following in app config:

'index' => 'index.php'

to

'index' => ''

This should solve your problem.